# Cannot login into an old wp site. Fatal Error: Cannot create references to/from string offsets

Tags: login, fatal-error

when trying to login to my old wp site I get a fatal error;

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot create references to/from string offsets in /www/htdocs/w0077893/worldstar/wp-includes/user.php:56 Stack trace: 
#0 /www/htdocs/w0077893/worldstar/wp-login.php(806): wp_signon('', '')
#1 {main} thrown in /www/htdocs/w0077893/worldstar/wp-includes/user.php on line 56
```

I have been looking into my phpMyAdmin, but I have no idea really what to do. Tried to find a line 56, but couldn't...delete plugin? Thank you.

Comment: it's possible it's very out of date and incompatible with the version of PHP your host is using, is that the entire stack trace? Which version of PHP and which version of WordPress is this? This has nothing to do with phpMyAdmin

Comment: thank you, the php is 7.2 the site is a subdomain, the main domain is working well, also wp. Any idea, what I could do? Thank you!!

Comment: and the version of WordPress? Have you made any changes to files in the `wp-includes` or `wp-admin` folders? And have you deactivated plugins by renaming their folders to see if that helps? At this point you should be going through the routine beginner debugging steps of trying to turn everything off then turn it back on one by one until the problem returns to identify the cause. Right now though this isn't really a specific question that fits into the format of this stack, but instead an open-ended investigation/discussion, this isn't a discussion forum, try to make this concrete and specific

Comment: I will try, thank you!